# OrderBy in laravel doesn't correctly order

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i have sql table called products and i want to order them according to price from low to high or vice versa

i have this code

```
$ts = Product::where('category_id',4)->where('status',5)->orderby('price','asc')->get();
    
     foreach($ts as $t){
         echo 'price => ' . $t->price.'<br>';
     }
```

i am printing the result to order price from low to high [ASC]

what i get is this

```
price => 10.00
price => 10.00
price => 3.00
price => 3.00
price => 3.00
price => 3.00
price => 4.00
price => 4.00
```

how 10 become before 3 while in asc order

Comment: Perhaps the price column was created with type string/VARCHAR?

Comment: yes bro , is this the reason?

Comment: Yes... it is sorted, but by text, not by numeric value. Change the type of the column to decimal and it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see `10` before `3` in a order column, its being ordered as text and not a number.

SQL is about structured data, so when creating tables ensure they are of the type related to the data. Dates are `date` or `datetime` etc. numbers are either `int`, `decimal`, `float` etc. If you don't, not only will ordering be hard, but also comparisons. All SQL servers do well on operations related to data stored correctly.

If in doubt, check the [manual on datatypes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-types.html) available.